# Can't import animated model in Powerpoint when using IK rig

Tags: rigging, export, gltf

I have animated two characters in Blender after rigged them and now I need to import the models in Powerpoint for a presentation.
Because I animated and rigged, i need to export them in .fbx or .gltf, the formats that Powerpoint is supposed to handle animation.

But when I do it the software generate different errors, saying the format is not handled, or just adding a grey case with written “can’t show the image”… I didn’t found any way to import properly my characters animated for the moment, and i think the problem is about rigging.

I rigged them both using Rigify, and particulary, i using the inverse kinematics to animate both of them because animate them in FK would be particulary long, and i’m not even sure it works…

I constated models that not use inverse kinematics (downloaded from sketchfab) are properly imported in Powerpoint, but what i need is now importing mines without having to restart all rigging.

If someone have an idea of why Powerpoint don’t seems to accept a model rigged with inverse kinematics, and how to solve this, it would help me a lot!
thanks and do not hesitate to ask any precision if needed.

Comment: It would be a good idea to test the models in other viewers: [threejs](http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) or [babylonjs](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) for glTF, or [FBX Review](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjQrsmE2ZPqAhUgITQIHXtEA9AQtwIwAHoECAEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.autodesk.com%2Fproducts%2Ffbx%2Ffbx-review&usg=AOvVaw0ZkB1g4D-vm6vH3IiyIbur) for FBX. If those can't open the model, the problem is in export. If they can, you may want to report a bug to Microsoft. I suspect that you may need to bake your IK to keyframes in Blender.

Comment: Hi, thanks for these solutions. I didn't knew It was possible to bake IK actions to FK, and it's precisly what i needed. I just tried and now the .fbx export of my baked model works! It just don't show all textures idk why but i think i will find a solution. Thanks a lot